# SSRS Query Designer - Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: soap, reporting-services

What is the corresponding SSRS Query to be used in the designer ?

The parameter is an object in C# as so

> public class A
>   {
>          [MessageBodyMember]
>          public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
>   }

The problem is with the Dictionary